# value not injecting in @ReuqestBody POJO from application-dev.properties - SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to Java SpringBoot and I am trying to inject a default value from application-dev.properties file.
Basically, the idea is to set default value to RequestObject's id property, default value being injected(/fetched) from application-dev.properties.

UseCase: In case, no data or blank data is being passed in request body of API, the code should set a default value (being injected/fetched from application-dev.properties).

Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value = PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
private @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ResponseBean<ResponseObject>> postController(
    final @Valid @RequestBody RequestObject request) throws Exception {
return serviceClass.service(request);
}
```

I did the following in RequestObject Class code

```
public class RequestObject {

    @Value("${package.default}")
    private String default_id;
    private String id = default_id;
    
    public String getId() {
     return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = !StringUtils.isBlank(id) ? id : default_id;
}
```

The above code is not working.
Please help or suggest a better way to achieve the requirement.

Note: If I hardcode the id value like id="abcd" while defining & in setter method, the code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject stuff(default values from application properties, other beans, etc.) only in spring managed components - those are classes annotated with `@Component`, `@Service` etc.

`RequestObject`, being a class you map request body to, **is not**, and **should not** be a component.

In order to inject default value from application.properties you need custom deserializer, which is a bean, and register this deserializer with `ObjectMapper`.

```
@Component
public class RequestObjectDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<RequestObject> {

    @Value("${your.property.here}")
    private String defaultValue;

    public RequestObjectDeserializer() {
        super(RequestObject.class);
    }

    @Override
    public RequestObject deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        //deserialize
    }
}
```

Then register it with already existing `Objectmapper`:

```
@Autowired
public void configObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper, RequestObjectDeserializer deserializer) {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(RequestObject.class, deserializer);
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
}
```

You can add above in any `@Configuration` class.

I'd say keeping the default value as static field in `RequestObject`, and having the logic in setter, is better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

why do you use `@Value("${package.default}")` in request body object? it should not work because they only mapped json into pojo object.  you can use and initiate default_id using `@Value("${package.default}")`  in your service class. after that you can set it your  `RequestObject` .